# Using a view in a XIB as inputAccessoryView

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, uitextview

I am implementing a custom inputAccessoryView in my app. I set up a UIView inside my ViewController XIB I want to use as the inputAccessoryView. I set up this method, but I don't know what code to use to "connect" the UIView in the ViewController to the UIView in the ViewController XIB. I have the UIView declared as an IBOutlet called accessoryView Here is the method I have set up:

```
-(UIView *)inputAccessoryView {
    if (addressBar) {

    }
    return addressBar;
}
```

What code do I need to use to use my UIView in the ViewController XIB as the UIView for the inputAccessoryView? Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out on my own. Simply added

```
addressBar.inputAccessoryView = accessoryView;
```

to my `viewDidLoad` method. Appears and dismisses with the keyboard on it's own. Not sure if there are any disadvantages to this method, but it's simple and it works.